# Creating an ASIO DSD Player

Tags: c, audio-player, asio, steinberg-asio

I'm trying to use the ASIO SDK v2.3 to create a Windows Console DSD audio player. I have used the hostsample example in the documentation. So far, I am able to play PCM based data successfully. Unfortunately, when switching to DSD sample format, I get a heap corruption error.

My sound card supports DSD ASIO Playback. Tested it with HQPlayer and foobar2000.

To switch to DSD format mode, I refer to the ASIO SDK documentation and use the ASIOFuture function to do the switching.

```
long init_asio_static_data(DriverInfo *asioDriverInfo)
{   
// collect the informational data of the driver
    // get the number of available channels
    ASIOIoFormat NeedThis = { kASIODSDFormat };
    if (ASE_SUCCESS != ASIOFuture(kAsioSetIoFormat, &NeedThis))
    {
        return -7;
    }
    .
    . 
    if (ASIOSetSampleRate(2822400) == ASE_OK)
    .
    .
}
```

This way, the driver will use the *SampleFormat* **ASIOSTDSDInt8LSB1** when copying more data into the buffer.

```
        case ASIOSTDSDInt8LSB1:
            memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize);
            break;
```

That's all I added into the example code. From this, I think that the driver would process and output the buffer in DSD mode.

Unfortunately, halfway through playback, I encounter a heap corruption error at

```
ASIOError ASIODisposeBuffers(void)
{
    if(!theAsioDriver)
        return ASE_NotPresent;
    return theAsioDriver->disposeBuffers(); //<--**Heap corruption**
}
```

Is something wrong with my code or the API?

I'm a beginner at C/C++ programming and audio programming as well so excuse the non technicality in this post..

Full code:

```
// hostsample.cpp : a simple ASIO host example.
// - instantiates the driver
// - get the information from the driver
// - built up some audio channels
// - plays silence for 20 seconds
// - destruct the driver
// Note: This sample cannot work with the "ASIO DirectX Driver" as it does
//       not have a valid Application Window handle, which is used as sysRef
//       on the Windows platform.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "asiosys.h"
#include "asio.h"
#include "asiodrivers.h"

// name of the ASIO device to be used
#if WINDOWS
//  #define ASIO_DRIVER_NAME    "ASIO Multimedia Driver"
#define ASIO_DRIVER_NAME    "Creative SBX AE series DSD ASIO"
#elif MAC
//  #define ASIO_DRIVER_NAME    "Apple Sound Manager"
#define ASIO_DRIVER_NAME    "ASIO Sample"
#endif

#define TEST_RUN_TIME  20.0     // run for 20 seconds
#define SAMPLERATE 2822400

enum {
    // number of input and outputs supported by the host application
    // you can change these to higher or lower values
    kMaxInputChannels = 32,
    kMaxOutputChannels = 32
};


// internal data storage
typedef struct DriverInfo
{
    // ASIOInit()
    ASIODriverInfo driverInfo;

    // ASIOGetChannels()
    long           inputChannels;
    long           outputChannels;

    // ASIOGetBufferSize()
    long           minSize;
    long           maxSize;
    long           preferredSize;
    long           granularity;

    // ASIOGetSampleRate()
    ASIOSampleRate sampleRate;

    // ASIOOutputReady()
    bool           postOutput;

    // ASIOGetLatencies ()
    long           inputLatency;
    long           outputLatency;

    // ASIOCreateBuffers ()
    long inputBuffers;  // becomes number of actual created input buffers
    long outputBuffers; // becomes number of actual created output buffers
    ASIOBufferInfo bufferInfos[kMaxInputChannels + kMaxOutputChannels]; // buffer info's

    // ASIOGetChannelInfo()
    ASIOChannelInfo channelInfos[kMaxInputChannels + kMaxOutputChannels]; // channel info's
    // The above two arrays share the same indexing, as the data in them are linked together

    // Information from ASIOGetSamplePosition()
    // data is converted to double floats for easier use, however 64 bit integer can be used, too
    double         nanoSeconds;
    double         samples;
    double         tcSamples;   // time code samples

    // bufferSwitchTimeInfo()
    ASIOTime       tInfo;           // time info state
    unsigned long  sysRefTime;      // system reference time, when bufferSwitch() was called

    // Signal the end of processing in this example
    bool           stopped;
} DriverInfo;


DriverInfo asioDriverInfo = { 0 };
ASIOCallbacks asioCallbacks;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// some external references
extern AsioDrivers* asioDrivers;
bool loadAsioDriver(char *name);

// internal prototypes (required for the Metrowerks CodeWarrior compiler)
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
long init_asio_static_data(DriverInfo *asioDriverInfo);
ASIOError create_asio_buffers(DriverInfo *asioDriverInfo);
unsigned long get_sys_reference_time();


// callback prototypes
void bufferSwitch(long index, ASIOBool processNow);
ASIOTime *bufferSwitchTimeInfo(ASIOTime *timeInfo, long index, ASIOBool processNow);
void sampleRateChanged(ASIOSampleRate sRate);
long asioMessages(long selector, long value, void* message, double* opt);



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
long init_asio_static_data(DriverInfo *asioDriverInfo)
{   // collect the informational data of the driver
    // get the number of available channels
    ASIOIoFormat NeedThis = { kASIODSDFormat };
    if (ASE_SUCCESS != ASIOFuture(kAsioSetIoFormat, &NeedThis))
    {
        return -7;
    }
    if (ASIOGetChannels(&asioDriverInfo->inputChannels, &asioDriverInfo->outputChannels) == ASE_OK)
    {
        printf("ASIOGetChannels (inputs: %d, outputs: %d);\n", asioDriverInfo->inputChannels, asioDriverInfo->outputChannels);

        // get the usable buffer sizes
        if (ASIOGetBufferSize(&asioDriverInfo->minSize, &asioDriverInfo->maxSize, &asioDriverInfo->preferredSize, &asioDriverInfo->granularity) == ASE_OK)
        {
            printf("ASIOGetBufferSize (min: %d, max: %d, preferred: %d, granularity: %d);\n",
                asioDriverInfo->minSize, asioDriverInfo->maxSize,
                asioDriverInfo->preferredSize, asioDriverInfo->granularity);

            // get the currently selected sample rate
            if (ASIOGetSampleRate(&asioDriverInfo->sampleRate) == ASE_OK)
            {
                printf("ASIOGetSampleRate (sampleRate: %f);\n", asioDriverInfo->sampleRate);
                if (ASIOCanSampleRate(SAMPLERATE) == ASE_OK)
                {
                    // Driver does not store it's internal sample rate, so set it to a know one.
                    // Usually you should check beforehand, that the selected sample rate is valid
                    // with ASIOCanSampleRate().
                    if (ASIOSetSampleRate(SAMPLERATE) == ASE_OK)
                    {
                        if (ASIOGetSampleRate(&asioDriverInfo->sampleRate) == ASE_OK)
                            printf("ASIOGetSampleRate (sampleRate: %f);\n", asioDriverInfo->sampleRate);
                        else
                            return -6;
                    }
                    else
                        return -5;
                }
                else
                    return -4;
                // check wether the driver requires the ASIOOutputReady() optimization
                // (can be used by the driver to reduce output latency by one block)
                if (ASIOOutputReady() == ASE_OK)
                    asioDriverInfo->postOutput = true;
                else
                    asioDriverInfo->postOutput = false;
                printf("ASIOOutputReady(); - %s\n", asioDriverInfo->postOutput ? "Supported" : "Not supported");

                return 0;
            }
            return -3;
        }
        return -2;
    }
    return -1;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// conversion from 64 bit ASIOSample/ASIOTimeStamp to double float
#if NATIVE_INT64
#define ASIO64toDouble(a)  (a)
#else
const double twoRaisedTo32 = 4294967296.;
#define ASIO64toDouble(a)  ((a).lo + (a).hi * twoRaisedTo32)
#endif

ASIOTime *bufferSwitchTimeInfo(ASIOTime *timeInfo, long index, ASIOBool processNow)
{   // the actual processing callback.
    // Beware that this is normally in a seperate thread, hence be sure that you take care
    // about thread synchronization. This is omitted here for simplicity.
    static long processedSamples = 0;

    // store the timeInfo for later use
    asioDriverInfo.tInfo = *timeInfo;

    // get the time stamp of the buffer, not necessary if no
    // synchronization to other media is required
    if (timeInfo->timeInfo.flags & kSystemTimeValid)
        asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds = ASIO64toDouble(timeInfo->timeInfo.systemTime);
    else
        asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds = 0;

    if (timeInfo->timeInfo.flags & kSamplePositionValid)
        asioDriverInfo.samples = ASIO64toDouble(timeInfo->timeInfo.samplePosition);
    else
        asioDriverInfo.samples = 0;

    if (timeInfo->timeCode.flags & kTcValid)
        asioDriverInfo.tcSamples = ASIO64toDouble(timeInfo->timeCode.timeCodeSamples);
    else
        asioDriverInfo.tcSamples = 0;

    // get the system reference time
    asioDriverInfo.sysRefTime = get_sys_reference_time();

#if WINDOWS && _DEBUG
    // a few debug messages for the Windows device driver developer
    // tells you the time when driver got its interrupt and the delay until the app receives
    // the event notification.
    static double last_samples = 0;
    char tmp[128];
    sprintf(tmp, "diff: %d / %d ms / %d ms / %d samples                 \n", asioDriverInfo.sysRefTime - (long)(asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds / 1000000.0), asioDriverInfo.sysRefTime, (long)(asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds / 1000000.0), (long)(asioDriverInfo.samples - last_samples));
    OutputDebugString(tmp);
    last_samples = asioDriverInfo.samples;
#endif

    // buffer size in samples
    long buffSize = asioDriverInfo.preferredSize;

    // perform the processing
    for (int i = 0; i < asioDriverInfo.inputBuffers + asioDriverInfo.outputBuffers; i++)
    {
        if (asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].isInput == false)
        {
            // OK do processing for the outputs only
            switch (asioDriverInfo.channelInfos[i].type)
            {
            case ASIOSTInt16LSB:
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 2);
                break;
            case ASIOSTInt24LSB:        // used for 20 bits as well
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 3);
                break;
            case ASIOSTInt32LSB:
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;
            case ASIOSTFloat32LSB:      // IEEE 754 32 bit float, as found on Intel x86 architecture
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;
            case ASIOSTFloat64LSB:      // IEEE 754 64 bit double float, as found on Intel x86 architecture
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 8);
                break;

                // these are used for 32 bit data buffer, with different alignment of the data inside
                // 32 bit PCI bus systems can more easily used with these
            case ASIOSTInt32LSB16:      // 32 bit data with 18 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32LSB18:      // 32 bit data with 18 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32LSB20:      // 32 bit data with 20 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32LSB24:      // 32 bit data with 24 bit alignment
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;

            case ASIOSTInt16MSB:
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 2);
                break;
            case ASIOSTInt24MSB:        // used for 20 bits as well
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 3);
                break;
            case ASIOSTInt32MSB:
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;
            case ASIOSTFloat32MSB:      // IEEE 754 32 bit float, as found on Intel x86 architecture
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;
            case ASIOSTFloat64MSB:      // IEEE 754 64 bit double float, as found on Intel x86 architecture
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 8);
                break;

                // these are used for 32 bit data buffer, with different alignment of the data inside
                // 32 bit PCI bus systems can more easily used with these
            case ASIOSTInt32MSB16:      // 32 bit data with 18 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32MSB18:      // 32 bit data with 18 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32MSB20:      // 32 bit data with 20 bit alignment
            case ASIOSTInt32MSB24:      // 32 bit data with 24 bit alignment
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize * 4);
                break;
            case ASIOSTDSDInt8LSB1:
            case ASIOSTDSDInt8MSB1:
            case ASIOSTDSDInt8NER8:     // DSD 8 bit data, 1 sample per byte. No Endianness required.
                memset(asioDriverInfo.bufferInfos[i].buffers[index], 0, buffSize);
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    // finally if the driver supports the ASIOOutputReady() optimization, do it here, all data are in place
    if (asioDriverInfo.postOutput)
        ASIOOutputReady();

    if (processedSamples >= asioDriverInfo.sampleRate * TEST_RUN_TIME)  // roughly measured
        asioDriverInfo.stopped = true;
    else
        processedSamples += buffSize;

    return 0L;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void bufferSwitch(long index, ASIOBool processNow)
{   // the actual processing callback.
    // Beware that this is normally in a seperate thread, hence be sure that you take care
    // about thread synchronization. This is omitted here for simplicity.

    // as this is a "back door" into the bufferSwitchTimeInfo a timeInfo needs to be created
    // though it will only set the timeInfo.samplePosition and timeInfo.systemTime fields and the according flags
    ASIOTime  timeInfo;
    memset(&timeInfo, 0, sizeof(timeInfo));

    // get the time stamp of the buffer, not necessary if no
    // synchronization to other media is required
    if (ASIOGetSamplePosition(&timeInfo.timeInfo.samplePosition, &timeInfo.timeInfo.systemTime) == ASE_OK)
        timeInfo.timeInfo.flags = kSystemTimeValid | kSamplePositionValid;

    bufferSwitchTimeInfo(&timeInfo, index, processNow);
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sampleRateChanged(ASIOSampleRate sRate)
{
    // do whatever you need to do if the sample rate changed
    // usually this only happens during external sync.
    // Audio processing is not stopped by the driver, actual sample rate
    // might not have even changed, maybe only the sample rate status of an
    // AES/EBU or S/PDIF digital input at the audio device.
    // You might have to update time/sample related conversion routines, etc.
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
long asioMessages(long selector, long value, void* message, double* opt)
{
    // currently the parameters "value", "message" and "opt" are not used.
    long ret = 0;
    switch (selector)
    {
    case kAsioSelectorSupported:
        if (value == kAsioResetRequest
            || value == kAsioEngineVersion
            || value == kAsioResyncRequest
            || value == kAsioLatenciesChanged
            // the following three were added for ASIO 2.0, you don't necessarily have to support them
            || value == kAsioSupportsTimeInfo
            || value == kAsioSupportsTimeCode
            || value == kAsioSupportsInputMonitor)
            ret = 1L;
        break;
    case kAsioResetRequest:
        // defer the task and perform the reset of the driver during the next "safe" situation
        // You cannot reset the driver right now, as this code is called from the driver.
        // Reset the driver is done by completely destruct is. I.e. ASIOStop(), ASIODisposeBuffers(), Destruction
        // Afterwards you initialize the driver again.
        asioDriverInfo.stopped;  // In this sample the processing will just stop
        ret = 1L;
        break;
    case kAsioResyncRequest:
        // This informs the application, that the driver encountered some non fatal data loss.
        // It is used for synchronization purposes of different media.
        // Added mainly to work around the Win16Mutex problems in Windows 95/98 with the
        // Windows Multimedia system, which could loose data because the Mutex was hold too long
        // by another thread.
        // However a driver can issue it in other situations, too.
        ret = 1L;
        break;
    case kAsioLatenciesChanged:
        // This will inform the host application that the drivers were latencies changed.
        // Beware, it this does not mean that the buffer sizes have changed!
        // You might need to update internal delay data.
        ret = 1L;
        break;
    case kAsioEngineVersion:
        // return the supported ASIO version of the host application
        // If a host applications does not implement this selector, ASIO 1.0 is assumed
        // by the driver
        ret = 2L;
        break;
    case kAsioSupportsTimeInfo:
        // informs the driver wether the asioCallbacks.bufferSwitchTimeInfo() callback
        // is supported.
        // For compatibility with ASIO 1.0 drivers the host application should always support
        // the "old" bufferSwitch method, too.
        ret = 1;
        break;
    case kAsioSupportsTimeCode:
        // informs the driver wether application is interested in time code info.
        // If an application does not need to know about time code, the driver has less work
        // to do.
        ret = 0;
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ASIOError create_asio_buffers(DriverInfo *asioDriverInfo)
{   // create buffers for all inputs and outputs of the card with the 
    // preferredSize from ASIOGetBufferSize() as buffer size
    long i;
    ASIOError result;

    // fill the bufferInfos from the start without a gap
    ASIOBufferInfo *info = asioDriverInfo->bufferInfos;

    // prepare inputs (Though this is not necessaily required, no opened inputs will work, too
    if (asioDriverInfo->inputChannels > kMaxInputChannels)
        asioDriverInfo->inputBuffers = kMaxInputChannels;
    else
        asioDriverInfo->inputBuffers = asioDriverInfo->inputChannels;
    for (i = 0; i < asioDriverInfo->inputBuffers; i++, info++)
    {
        info->isInput = ASIOTrue;
        info->channelNum = i;
        info->buffers[0] = info->buffers[1] = 0;
    }

    // prepare outputs
    if (asioDriverInfo->outputChannels > kMaxOutputChannels)
        asioDriverInfo->outputBuffers = kMaxOutputChannels;
    else
        asioDriverInfo->outputBuffers = asioDriverInfo->outputChannels;
    for (i = 0; i < asioDriverInfo->outputBuffers; i++, info++)
    {
        info->isInput = ASIOFalse;
        info->channelNum = i;
        info->buffers[0] = info->buffers[1] = 0;
    }

    // create and activate buffers
    result = ASIOCreateBuffers(asioDriverInfo->bufferInfos,
        asioDriverInfo->inputBuffers + asioDriverInfo->outputBuffers,
        asioDriverInfo->preferredSize, &asioCallbacks);
    if (result == ASE_OK)
    {
        // now get all the buffer details, sample word length, name, word clock group and activation
        for (i = 0; i < asioDriverInfo->inputBuffers + asioDriverInfo->outputBuffers; i++)
        {
            asioDriverInfo->channelInfos[i].channel = asioDriverInfo->bufferInfos[i].channelNum;
            asioDriverInfo->channelInfos[i].isInput = asioDriverInfo->bufferInfos[i].isInput;
            result = ASIOGetChannelInfo(&asioDriverInfo->channelInfos[i]);
            if (result != ASE_OK)
                break;
        }

        if (result == ASE_OK)
        {
            // get the input and output latencies
            // Latencies often are only valid after ASIOCreateBuffers()
            // (input latency is the age of the first sample in the currently returned audio block)
            // (output latency is the time the first sample in the currently returned audio block requires to get to the output)
            result = ASIOGetLatencies(&asioDriverInfo->inputLatency, &asioDriverInfo->outputLatency);
            if (result == ASE_OK)
                printf("ASIOGetLatencies (input: %d, output: %d);\n", asioDriverInfo->inputLatency, asioDriverInfo->outputLatency);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // load the driver, this will setup all the necessary internal data structures
    if (loadAsioDriver((char*)ASIO_DRIVER_NAME))
    {
        // initialize the driver
        if (ASIOInit(&asioDriverInfo.driverInfo) == ASE_OK)
        {
            printf("asioVersion:   %d\n"
                "driverVersion: %d\n"
                "Name:          %s\n"
                "ErrorMessage:  %s\n",
                asioDriverInfo.driverInfo.asioVersion, asioDriverInfo.driverInfo.driverVersion,
                asioDriverInfo.driverInfo.name, asioDriverInfo.driverInfo.errorMessage);
            if (init_asio_static_data(&asioDriverInfo) == 0)
            {
                // ASIOControlPanel(); you might want to check wether the ASIOControlPanel() can open

                // set up the asioCallback structure and create the ASIO data buffer
                asioCallbacks.bufferSwitch = &bufferSwitch;
                asioCallbacks.sampleRateDidChange = &sampleRateChanged;
                asioCallbacks.asioMessage = &asioMessages;
                asioCallbacks.bufferSwitchTimeInfo = &bufferSwitchTimeInfo;
                if (create_asio_buffers(&asioDriverInfo) == ASE_OK)
                {
                    if (ASIOStart() == ASE_OK)
                    {
                        // Now all is up and running
                        fprintf(stdout, "\nASIO Driver started succefully.\n\n");
                        while (!asioDriverInfo.stopped)
                        {
#if WINDOWS
                            Sleep(100); // goto sleep for 100 milliseconds
#elif MAC
                            unsigned long dummy;
                            Delay(6, &dummy);
#endif
                            fprintf(stdout, "%d ms / %d ms / %d samples", asioDriverInfo.sysRefTime, (long)(asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds / 1000000.0), (long)asioDriverInfo.samples);

                            // create a more readable time code format (the quick and dirty way)
                            double remainder = asioDriverInfo.tcSamples;
                            long hours = (long)(remainder / (asioDriverInfo.sampleRate * 3600));
                            remainder -= hours * asioDriverInfo.sampleRate * 3600;
                            long minutes = (long)(remainder / (asioDriverInfo.sampleRate * 60));
                            remainder -= minutes * asioDriverInfo.sampleRate * 60;
                            long seconds = (long)(remainder / asioDriverInfo.sampleRate);
                            remainder -= seconds * asioDriverInfo.sampleRate;
                            fprintf(stdout, " / TC: %2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d:%5.5d", (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds, (long)remainder);

                            fprintf(stdout, "     \r");
#if !MAC
                            fflush(stdout);
#endif
                        }
                        ASIOStop();
                    }
                    ASIODisposeBuffers();
                }
            }
            ASIOExit();
        }
        asioDrivers->removeCurrentDriver();
    }
    return 0;
}


unsigned long get_sys_reference_time()
{   // get the system reference time
#if WINDOWS
    return timeGetTime();
#elif MAC
    static const double twoRaisedTo32 = 4294967296.;
    UnsignedWide ys;
    Microseconds(&ys);
    double r = ((double)ys.hi * twoRaisedTo32 + (double)ys.lo);
    return (unsigned long)(r / 1000.);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm creating the dsd audio player too. Did you solve this problem.

```
 ASIOIoFormat NeedThis = { kASIODSDFormat };
    if (ASE_SUCCESS != ASIOFuture(kAsioSetIoFormat, &NeedThis))
    {
        return -7;
    }
```

Maybe these phrases will be put in the end of the function.